# Why aren't posts dated with the year?

Tags: discussion

Why does this website not give the year when writing the date for a posting? "June 26" could be any year, and the answer given in a past year might have become out of date..

Comment: Answers given in previous years do show the date. Look for anything by [Richard](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/84/richard), for example.

Answer (score 4):

If no year is shown, it belongs to the current year. If the post is from a previous year, it will show the date. Since this site only got rolling in the last few months of 2011, you'll have to go back to some early posts to spot this.